# How do we define fractional Sobolev spaces on manifolds?

Tags: analysis, sobolev-spaces

Fix $s > 1/2.$ The trace operator is surjective from $H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ to $H^{s-\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$

If $\Omega$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with smooth boundary, I know there is a bounded trace operator from $H^{1}(\Omega)$ to $L^{2}(\partial \Omega).$ Intuitively, the image of the trace should be $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega),$ by the result I commented at the beginning... But my problem is, How can we define such a space? via local coordinates? I do not see why that will necessarily work, I cannot work out the details. Of course, I cannot compute inmediately the Fourier transform on the surface, so describing the space $H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\partial \Omega)$ seems like a very hard thing to me.

Comment: I don't think you can "define" such space via classical method or opinion. This is why we using Fourior transform to extend the definition of sobolev space...

Comment: I know that. I don't know what you mean, or what have you understood from my question.

Comment: The most reasonable thing is to *define* $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$ as the image of the trace operator. The reason why this is ok, is because $1/2$ is "critical" in the sense of scaling.  Equivalently you can view $H^{1/2}(\partial)$ as the closure of smooth functions on the boundary with respect to the $H^1$ bulk induced norm on them.